# Finding cost function

Tags: optimization, self-learning, economics

The production function is as follows

$$f(z)=(z_1+z_2)(z_3+z_4)$$

Find the cost function?

What I did is as follows. But I am not sure about my solution. How do you solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is a production and a cost function?

Comment: Production function is $f(z)$ which I wrote in the top of the question ( by latex format). I am looking for cost function. @dmh

Comment: I am not familiar with those terms

Comment: So, any users who are familiar with these terms look at my question. Thank you! @dmh

Comment: This is economical mathematics. I guess this is not your interest @dmh

Comment: And why downvote? Please explain ! Thanks

Comment: Explain the variables and post the exercise.